# Is it possible to make Debezium engine work with mysql having binglog_format as MIXED instead of ROW

Tags: java, apache-kafka-connect, mysql-connector, debezium, mysqlbinlog

I'm looking for an alternate way for Debezium to work with mysql database.

**Reason** - I'm trying to connect to production database and the server which I'm trying to connect has 85 databases and binlog is shared with all those databases.
Right now we have `binlog_format=MIXED` and it is not an easy work to change it to `ROW`

Is there any way we can tweak at the client end or at the database end to get this done, since `MIXED is a combination of ROW AND STATEMENT`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Debezium requires the `ROW` binlog mode. If you cannot change this on your production database, one alternative could be to set up MySQL replication to a replica, and set the binlog mode to `ROW` on that one. Then set up Debezium to stream changes off of the replica. That way you don't have to modify the settings of your primary system, but of course latency will be slightly increased due to the additional hop.

Comment: If am changing this way the replication machine won't reflect the records. because master machine configured with MIXED

Comment: Did you have to enable GTID on replica in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with a large production MySQL database and we need to migrate all replicas to the row format. Unfortunately, we have found no other solution.